# ListView inside ColumnLayout inside ScrollView not filling available height/width

Tags: qt, listview, qml, scrollview

I want to display some data in TextFeild, CheckBoxes and some Button and display long a list after that. I want entire page to be scrollable and not just ListView. How Can I achive that ?

Here is what I came up until now:-

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView { //comment out this
        anchors.fill: parent //comment out this
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 5

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100
                color: "green"
            }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100
                color: "red"
            }

            ListView {
                model : 20
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                delegate: Frame {
                    Label {
                        text: modelData + "th Item"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } //comment out this
}
```

This does not work. It only shows one cell of ListView and its not scrollable. How can I make ListView fill the height/width and make entire page scrollable ?

Comment: Is your goal for the green and red Rectangles to scroll with the ListView? You could put them in the ListView's header and get rid of the ColumnLayout.

Comment: @JarMan. Yes. that is my goal. But I have another Rectacgle as header for ListView with `headerPositioning : ListView.PullBackHeader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that a `ScrollView` cannot scroll if it's contents are the same height as the `ScrollView`. It needs the contents to be bigger. Otherwise there's nothing to scroll to. So a `ColumnLayout` that fits to the parent's height is not going to work. A `Column` is better than a `ColumnLayout` in this case because it will grow to height of its children, rather than resizing its children to its own size.

The second problem is that the `ListView` was not figuring out its height correctly. I'm not entirely sure why not, but I was able to get your example working by using the `childrenRect.height`.

```
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent 
        Column {
            width: parent.width
            spacing: 5

            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 100
                color: "green"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 100
                color: "red"
            }

            ListView {
                model : 20
                width: parent.width
                height: childrenRect.height
                delegate: Frame {
                    Label {
                        text: modelData + "th Item"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```